# How can I use the same content file document in subcase without reinserting the same

Tags: case, email2case, content

I have a parent case on which three files are uploaded; now while creating the sub case from the related case section, these attachment should automatically visible in the subcase as well.

One solution: I did by re-inserting the same parent files in the sub case as well.
with these the same file is created multiple times.

Is their any way I can use the same file in multiple cases without re-inserting the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to **re-insert** the attachments for the child cases or vice-versa, you should use [VF page as related list](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003207&type=1) and in that VF page build logic to check

1. if the current case has a parent
2. if yes, then soql [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)by passing the `parentId` of current case to the soql, something like
   `SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: caseParentId`
3. display those records on the VF page and finally place your VF page on the Case page layout.

P.S. You could do it both ways,

1. On child cases, showing Parent files
2. On parent cases, showing children files (that would be your assignment ) :-)

> **Edit (4/3/17) - Workaroud #2** (on the request of the OP)

I have done linking single note (enhanced) to multiple records, but didn't try linking file with multiple records. I just tried it in my developer edition and it worked, although, will be a bit overkill as compared to solution#1 (will discuss this later)

**Groundwork**

So, basically, for each file that you link to a record, a `ContentDocumentLink` record is created, that depicts the relationship between the **file**(`ContentDocument`) and the linked **object** (i.e. in your case it is`case`). `LinkedEntityId` is the key field that you use for this purpose, creating another record with the `LinkedEntityId` set to the **ChildCaseId** will have the same file linked to the childcase(s).

**Triggers at work**

To automate the theory explained above, you need to have two triggers,

1. one on **ContentDocumentLink** - Insert event

   - check if the `LinkedEntityId` of the ContentDocLink record is a case
   - if yes, check if it has **children**
   - if yes, get all children
   - create a list of **ContentDocLink** with **LinkedEntityId** being populated with the ChildCases.
   - **insert** the list.
2. second on **Case** (Insert and Update)

   - Every time a case is **inserted**, check if it has a Parent,
   - if yes, check for files associated with parent
   - if files found, associate those files using ContentDocLink list logic explained above and Insert the list.
   - on **update**, check

     - if a parent is assigned to a case or
     - a file is associated to a case
   - check for files, and associate them with the child case(s).

Just keep in mind, in both approaches, you are not creating multiple copies of files, in #2, you are just going to create a link record to the same file already present in your system.

I hope, the above explanation should be enough get this thing done. Only part remaining is writing those **triggers** or **VF page**, which I'm sure, you can do better than myself. :)

Comment: OP is asking about Files and not attachments

Comment: @Mahmood: Thanks mahmood, with an inline VF page yes I can do it , but is it possible without an inline VF page. LIke some link point to that file in sub case. Not the actual file but a link which will point to the file in the child case. ContentDocumentId is the file Id ,if I append that Id in the URL the file will be opened. Is their any possibility to do something like that ?

Comment: Alternative (no inline VF page): When subcase is created, use after insert trigger to create additional ContenrDocumentLinks to existing parent Case Files but point at child Case. Then as Files are CRUD on parent case, new CDL can be added or removed from all children cases to keep in sync.  This allows children to have unique Files as well as lists of files from parent

Comment: @cropredy: Are you referring to the workaround #2, I added later to my question, but seems kinda different. If it is not the case, can you please edit the answer and include your approach as well, or add yours as an answer.

Comment: Yes - your workaround#2 is what my comment suggested - my comment may have predated your edit

Comment: It did, right? :P
I had created multiple links with enhanced notes (ContentNote) in the past but didn't try it with Files, but I tried it couple of days ago and it worked. Your comment just seemed a bit different so I thought I should ask.